# How to use mapping in this javascript object? Doesnt work

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I have this object:

```
{"act": 0, "add": "Nsnshs", "addCoord": {"_latitude": 0, "_longitude": 0}, "ble_address": "", "city": "hfhgf", "device_id": "", "last_location": {"_latitude": 0, "_longitude": 0}, "nam": "James", "personalID": "hshwwh17717", "registered_by": "fghfghfghfgh", "role": "patient", "start_treatment": {"_nanoseconds": 492000000, "_seconds": 1593634435}, "surn": "Bond", "tel": "2424554", "update_freq": 21600, "update_time": {"_nanoseconds": 492000000, "_seconds": 1593634435}}
```

I am printing it like this `console.log(documentSnapshot.data());`

and I would like to use mapping to add some new elements to it. I tried this:

```
var dataSource = documentSnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { ...doc.data(), doc_id: doc.id } });
```

but it throws this error:

> **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'documentSnapshot.docs.map')**

Now, I can see that `.docs` doesnt exist in the object but even if I try with `.data()` it still shows the same error. So, what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Priting without .data()**

```
console.log(documentSnapshot)

{"_data": {"act": 0, "add": "Nsnshs", "addCoord": {"_latitude": 0, "_longitude": 0}, "ble_address": "", "city": "hfdfhdfgh", "device_id": "", "last_location": {"_latitude": 0, "_longitude": 0}, "nam": "James", "personalID": "hshwwh17717", "registered_by": "fghgfhfghfgh", "role": "patient", "start_treatment": {"_nanoseconds": 492000000, "_seconds": 1593634435}, "surn": "Bond", "tel": "2424554", "update_freq": 21600, "update_time": {"_nanoseconds": 492000000, "_seconds": 1593634435}}, "_exists": true, "_metadata": {"_metadata": [false, false]}, "_ref": {"_documentPath": {"_parts": [Array]}, "_firestore": {"_app": [FirebaseApp], "_config": [Object], "_customUrlOrRegion": undefined, "_nativeModule": [Object], "_referencePath": [FirestorePath], "_transactionHandler": [FirestoreTransactionHandler]}}}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to loop over the value of a key that does not exist?

Comment: @hev1 I tried with `data()`and still doesn't work. `data()` exists as you can see above

Comment: Do you mean `_data`? There is no key called `data`.

Comment: Isn't map only for Arrays?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what your goal is here.  We also need to see more code, especially the code that created `documentSnapshot`.  Right now, it's just hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are calling the map method on an object.  The map method only sits on the array prototype so this would not work.  If you would like to combine two objects together to add data you can do the following

Spreading the object to a new object, and then add data to it

```
const newObject = {...documentSnapshot, ...theOtherObjectYouWantToCombine}
```

You can also use a for in loop to add on to the object, but beware this will overwrite any properties that have the same name in the other data you are trying to apply

```
for(const key in otherObject) {
documentSnapshot[key] = otherObject[key]
}
```